# Validation does not work with Spring Boot + RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot project with Rest Controller, where I need to validate input data.
Here is what I have in my POM:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my Controller. Also I've tried to place Validated annotation on the whole class instead of Valid on method. Also, I've tried to place Valid(ated) annotations on Service class:

```
@Slf4j @RestController
//@Validated placing this annotation here didn't helped either
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    private final Counter requestCounter;

    public MyController(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.requestCounter = meterRegistry.counter("my.counter");
    }

    @PostMapping("/somepath")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(@RequestBody @Valid InputMessage im) {
        log.debug("Received message {}",im);
        requestCounter.increment();
        try {
            myService.handleDoc(im);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Done", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            log.error("Error with document with message id {}",im.getId(), ex);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Failed to process request", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

InputMessage class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
@Data
public class InputMessage {
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    public String id;

    @NotBlank @Email
    public String email;

    @NotBlank //the same with @NotNull here
    public Integer status;

    @NotBlank
    public String error;
}
```

No matter which data I send in request - I receive 201 Created. This works the same both in tests and via starting application and using postman. Also, I've tries to remove try-catch, leaving only counter incrementation and handleDoc method.

What should I do to enable validation?

Comment: @ NotBlank
public Integer status;
change to @ NotNull, try again?

Comment: this also doesnt help(

Comment: Why are all fields public? Should be private with public getters/setters. Probably this confuses the validation software. Hope it helps.

Comment: You should add @Validated above your MyController

Comment: Pawan.Java, I've tried this, it did not helped(

Comment: Mar-Z, making fields of InputMessage didn't helped(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: changing all packages from `javax` to `jakarta` in imports solved an issue...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fix your dependencies, for validation this three are enough:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also `@NotBlank` validator doesn't apply to integers, you should use `@NotNull`

```
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
@Data
public class InputMessage {
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    public String id;

    @NotBlank @Email
    public String email;

    @NotNull
    public Integer status;

    @NotBlank
    public String error;
}
```

Comment: With all these fixes I recieve OK when sending {
"id": "012345678901234567890123456789",
"status": 7,
"error":"",
"email": "sdfsds"
}